# What is the correct Latinate prefix for honey-eaters?

Tags: single-word-requests, prefixes, latin

In English, a vegetarian who eats eggs and dairy products can be referred to as an [*ovo-lacto vegetarian*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovo-lacto_vegetarianism). By [the same token](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_and_Latin_roots_in_English), could a person who eats honey but is otherwise vegan be meaningfully called a *mell-vegan*?

Comment: Maybe *mellivegan* by analogy from *mellifluous*. Maybe too easy to confuse with *millivegan*. In any case, you can call anybody anything. The onus will simply be on you to define the term in any context in which you use it (unless/until it takes off).

Comment: Do you mean those who eat no animal products -beyond- honey? I can't find any precedent for that term. Also it doesn't sound right. 'mello-vegan'? But anyway, no one will know what you mean.

Comment: @MετάEd is a millivegan one thousandth of a vegan? :)

Comment: @MarkBeadles Exactly! Maybe a unit of measurement for compassion?

Comment: @MarkBeadles So I guess a millivegan is someone who eats meat 99.9% of the time, but .1% of the time refuses to do so. "Mellovegan" sounds to me like a vegan who doesn't get excited about the subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Latin, 'honey' was [*mel*, with the oblique stem of *melli-*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mel#Latin). In English we generally use the oblique stem for Latin and Greek words, so the correct prefix would be **melli-**.

(Note: the genus of Honeyeater birds are the [Meliphagidae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meliphagidae), which unlike many biological names is from the Greek: *meli*- + *phag*-. Note the single **l** in the Greek form.)

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no consensus of how to call a "vegan who also eats honey", but following the list of prefixes and the occasional [forum](http://www.veggieboards.com/t/8033/types-of-vegetarians-vegans-or-what-am-i-and-how-can-i-be-better/30#post_225660) [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rec.food.veg/YFjRp_Xivys), *mellivegan* seems to be more common than other options.

Using the [strict definition](http://www.vegsource.com/jo/essays/namegame.htm) of *vegan* from when the term was coined in 1944, a person who eats honey isn't a vegan. This is different from the term *ovo-lacto vegetarian* because *vegetarians* are [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarianism) as "abstaining from the consumption of meat and by-products of animal slaughter", neither of which explicitly excludes eggs and milk. So an *ovo-lacto vegetarian* is still a true *vegetarian*, whereas a *mellivegan* isn't a vegan.

EDIT:

However, definitions change and the consumption of honey is [debated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegan#Honey_and_other_insect_products) within the vegan community, so a *mellivegan* can be considered a vegan.

Comment: A good friend of mine (a vegan) told me that, in the vegan community, honey is "a gray area." To eat (or not eat) honey might depend on your motivation for choosing a vegan lifestyle.

Comment: I think this answer relies too much on "strict definitions" which I believe are not nearly so strict as the answer implies.

Comment: Hmm, I'd think that eating honey would be comparable to drinking milk: both are products produced by animals, but which do not require killing the animal to consume them. But I'm not a vegan and I don't think I've ever known a vegan (as opposed to a vegetarian), so maybe I'm just missing the point of their thinking.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for the comment. I'm not a vegan so I wasn't aware of the debate.  I added that to my answer.

Comment: @MετάEd I added clarification that the "strict definition" was taken from history and that definitions change.

Comment: @Jay: I'm no vegan, either, so I'm a little bit outside my realm of expertise, but the gist is a focus on the _treatment_ of the animal, not just the _killing_ of the animal. I remember something about cows being kept perpetually lactating so that humans can have the luxury of milk on their cereal and in their coffee. (My friend has since moved cross-country, so I can't readily get a memory refresher.)

Comment: @J.R. Hmm, wandering off-topic, but if that's the reasoning, then presumably the same product could be acceptable if it was obtained in one way but unacceptable if obtained in another. i.e. it would not be "I don't eat honey" but "I will only eat honey that was harvested by method X". I'm not saying such a position would be irrational: e.g. I would sympathize with someone who said that he was boycotting company Y because they sold products made by slave labor in some country where that was legal or winked at. Maybe I'll find a vegan website and ask what their actual position is.

Answer (score 2):

You could call a honey-eating vegan a ***mellivorous*** vegans, since *mellivorous* exactly means  honey-eating.

But wouldn’t *honey-eating* (or *non–honey-eating*) be good enough? I ask because I don’t think looking for a fancy word here is necessarily a good idea. You never want to confuse people on things like this, and fancy words will always confuse (some) people.

For example, I  know *non-**mycophagous** vegetarians*, but they avoid describing themselves as such for fear of being fed food with (intentional) fungus in it.

Similarly, although
most vegetarians will eat cheese only if is vegetarian cheese, since normally cheese is  made with [animal-derived rennet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rennet), it would not be helpful to invent a specialized technical term for this — and indeed might even be counterproductive.

It’s like how you never use fancy words to describe food allergies, for fear of feeding someone something one mustn’t.  Best just to say what the deal is using simple words that everybody can understand without a classical dictionary on hand.

Comment: I thought cheese was ok for vegetarians, but just not for vegans.

Comment: @joulesm That depends on the cheese.  Vegans do not eat anything that comes from an animal, no matter how cruelly or kindly derived. Vegetarians do not eat cheese made with rennet that derives from ground-up cow stomachs — for what I should hope are obvious reasons. See the difference? There are vegetarian cheeses, because it doesn’t *have* to be made with cow guts.